# CFNetwork internal error

Tags: ios, networking, cfnetwork, nsurlprotocol

I'm creating my own NSURLProtocol with a caching system and I'm seeing this on the console:

4676: CFNetwork internal error (0xc01a:/SourceCache/CFNetwork_Sim/CFNetwork-609.1.4/Connection/URLConnectionClient.cpp:558

Any idea what is causing this?

There's no indication that any of the traffic is not being handled correctly at the current point where this shows up. The response is cached, the server sends back 304 not modified and I load the cached response and then while stepping out another thread logs that error.

Comment: Nope. I haven't seen the error in a while. If I find it again and find a fix I will update this.

Answer (score 1):

For me its was appear when I forgot set

```
setHTTPMethod:
```

For  NSMutableURLRequest